# A result of Chebychev and an $\epsilon$ away from Bertrand's postulate

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I came across the following result in a number theory book. In proving a result of Chebychev that there exist positive constants $x_0$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $$ c_1 \frac{x}{\log x} \le \pi(x) \le c_2\frac{x}{\log x}$$ for all $x>x_0$, the following bounds on $\psi(x)$ were used
$$ x\log 2 + O(\log x) \le \psi(x) \le 2x\log 2 + O(\log^2(x))$$ together with the result that
$$\frac{\psi(x)}{x} = \frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x} + o(1)$$

The author says that for any $c_1 < \log 2$ and any $c_2 > 2\log 2$ the theorem holds. In an attempt to fill the details, I did the following:

starting from $$ x\log 2 + O(\log x) \le \psi(x) \le 2x\log 2 + O(\log^2(x)),$$ divide through by $x$ to obtain
$$\log 2 + o(1) \le \frac{\psi(x)}{x} \le 2\log2 + o(1)$$

Now, replace $\frac{\psi(x)}{x}$ with $\frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x} + o(1)$ so that
$$\log 2 + o(1) \le \frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x} + o(1) \le 2\log2 + o(1)$$
Here's a step I'm not sure of and need clarification: can the little $o$ term in the middle be subtracted across the board to get
$$\log 2 + o(1) \le \frac{\pi(x)\log x}{x}\le 2\log2 + o(1)$$
$$\frac{x}{\log x}(\log 2 + o(1)) \le \pi(x) \le \frac{x}{\log x}(2\log2 + o(1))$$ and hence for any $c_1 < \log2, c_2 > 2\log 2$ the theorem follows?

Secondly, the author says that since $\frac{2\log 2}{\log 2}=2,$ a corollary of this result is that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a prime number in the interval $[x, (2+\epsilon)x]$ for all $x > x_0(\epsilon)$. I do not see this immediately. How can this be verified?

Comment: (1) Yes, the $o(1)$ in the middle can be subsumed into the other $o(1)$s as you propose. (2) If there is no prime number in the interval $[x,(2+\varepsilon)x]$, then $\pi(x) = \pi\big( (2+\varepsilon)x \big)$; show that this violates the upper and lower bounds you derived.

Comment: @GregMartin assuming $\pi(x) = \pi((2+\epsilon)x)$, I have tried to look at the difference $0 = \pi(x) - \pi((2+\epsilon)x)$ and the ratio $1 = \frac{\pi(x)} {\pi((2+\epsilon)x)}$ but can't seem to derive a contradiction

Comment: Either one should work—just insert the Chebyshev lower bound for one and the upper bound for the other....

Comment: I have $0 = \pi((2+\epsilon)x) - \pi(x) \ge \frac{c_1 x(2+\epsilon)}{\log(x(2+\epsilon))} - \frac{c_2 x}{\log x}$. How can I deduce this is positive for large $x$?

Comment: I'll let you puzzle that out: the denominators are practically equal for large $x$ (some algebra is needed to turn that observation into a deduction).

Comment: @GregMartin if the edit I made above is correct, am I right to say that the purpose of the $\epsilon > 0$ is to ensure that $\frac{x}{\log x}o(1)$ is not perhaps negative as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: More accurately, to ensure that $c_1\varepsilon+o(1)$ is not negative. (In the first sentence of your verification, you should say "for some $x$" instead of "for all $x$".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GregMartin's guidance, here's how to verify the last claim that was made.

Suppose for some $\epsilon > 0$ there is no prime in the interval $[x, (2+\epsilon)x]$ for some $x$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
0 = \pi((2+\epsilon)x) - \pi(x) &\ge \frac{c_1(2+\epsilon)x}{\log((2+\epsilon)x)} - \frac{c_2x}{\log x} \\
&= \frac{c_1(2+\epsilon)x}{K + \log x} - \frac{c_2x}{\log x},  \ \ \text{ where } K=\log(2+\epsilon) \\
&= \frac{x}{\log x} \left(\frac{c_1(2+\epsilon)}{1+K/\log x} - c_2\right) \\
&= \frac{x}{\log x} \left(\frac{c_1(2+\epsilon)}{1+o(1)} - c_2\right) \ \ \text{ for } x \text{ large}\\
&= \frac{x}{\log x} \left(c_1(2+\epsilon) +o(1) - c_2\right) \\
&= \frac{x}{\log x}(c_1\epsilon + o(1)) \ \ \text{ since } 2c_1 - c_2 = o(1) \\
\end{align}$$
which is positive as $x \rightarrow \infty$, a contradiction.